# How to generate 100 unique 10-char strings with chance.js

Tags: javascript, chancejs

I want to generate 100 unique 10-char strings using chance.js. I use the code below, but it returns an error. Anyone knows how to make it work?

```js
let res = chance.unique(chance.string({ length: 10, casing: 'upper', alpha: true, numeric: true }), 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chance/1.1.6/chance.min.js"></script>
```

The following works, but it doesn't returns fixed-length strings.

```js
let res = chance.unique(chance.string, 100);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chance/1.1.6/chance.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your attempt is that you are not passing a *function* to `chance.unique`, but instead *execute* `chance.string`.

In order to pass a function, which *will be* called with the options you want, you can pass an anonymous function, or let `bind` do that for you:

```js
let res = chance.unique(chance.string.bind(chance, { length: 10, casing: 'upper', alpha: true, numeric: true }), 100);

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chance/1.1.6/chance.min.js"></script>
```